# datatable replace zero with null or empty string via linq

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a datatable which contains some values with 0s. Now I want to replace all the 0s with null or "".

Sample Datatable

```
A       B       C
6       0       7
0       7       0
5       0       4
```

Expected

```
A       B       C
6               7
        7        
5               4
```

I can do it via for loop but is it possible to do it via LINQ ?

Comment: Link is for _querying_ not _updating_. You could project your data to a _new_ `DataTable` but there's nothing wrong with using a loop. Or change the query that populates the `DataTable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `LINQ` supports querying and not updating, the best you could do is make use of its querying to get all the column info of a `DataTable` and then update your cell one-by-one.

One way to do it is by implementing a method whose input is `DataTable` to do the task:

```
private void dtChangeZeroToNull (DataTable dataTable){
    List<string> dcNames = dataTable.Columns
                            .Cast<DataColumn>()
                            .Select(x => x.ColumnName)
                            .ToList(); //This querying of the Column Names, you could do with LINQ
    foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows) //This is the part where you update the cell one by one
        foreach (string columnName in dcNames)
            row[columnName] = (int)row[columnName] == 0 ? DBNull.Value : row[columnName];               
}
```

And there you go.

Now, to change each cell whose value is `0` to `DBNull` in a `DataTable`, you can simply call the method:

```
dtChangeZeroToNull (dataTable);
```

Note: Seems like the `DataTable.Rows` and `DataTable.Columns` do not implement `LINQ` `Select`. Otherwise we could immediately do this

```
List<string> dtcolumnNames = dataTable.Columns.Select(x => x.ToString());
```

Without a need of `Cast<DataColumn>`

Answer (score 4):

You have to do something like this.

```
 //I am constructing a data table here. You already have this I guess.
        var dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("A", typeof(int)) { AllowDBNull = true });
        dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("B", typeof(int)) { AllowDBNull = true });
        dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("C", typeof(int)) { AllowDBNull = true });

//Assign values
        DataRow row1 = dataTable.NewRow();
        row1["A"] = 6;
        row1["B"] = 0;
        row1["C"] = 7;
        dataTable.Rows.Add(row1);

        DataRow row2 = dataTable.NewRow();
        row2["A"] = 0;
        row2["B"] = 7;
        row2["C"] = 0;
        dataTable.Rows.Add(row2);

        DataRow row3 = dataTable.NewRow();
        row3["A"] = 5;
        row3["B"] = 0;
        row3["C"] = 4;
        dataTable.Rows.Add(row3);

//This is what you need.
        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            if ((int)row["A"] == 0)
            {
                row["A"] = DBNull.Value;
            } 
            if ((int) row["B"] == 0)
            {
                row["B"] = DBNull.Value;
            }
            if ((int) row["C"] == 0)
            {
                row["C"] = DBNull.Value;
            }
        }

//test the changes
        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("" + row["A"] + "; " + row["B"] + "; " + row["C"]);
        }
```